# how does the infinite place of $\mathbb{Q}$ ramify in the Galois closure of $x^3-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $L$ be the splitting field (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of $x^3-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. We have $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=6$. Let $p$ denote the infinite/archimedian prime of $\mathbb{Q}$, given by the inclusion $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$. How does $p$ "factor" in $L$? Basically, what are the ways in which $p$ be extended to $L \to \mathbb{C}$? I'm guessing there are three pairs of complex conjugate embeddings, and they are not too hard to guess - somehow coming from factoring $(x^3-2)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$ where $r_1 \in\mathbb{R}$ and $r_2, r_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ are complex conjugate pairs. I think my problem is I am having trouble writing down $L$ as an abstract field, and not with a particular embedding into $\mathbb{C}$: I know $L\cong \mathbb{Q}[r_1, r_2, r_3]$ but there are six different such isomorphisms. How should I write $L$ to be able to describe these isomorphisms a bit more explicitly? I know $Q[x]/(x^3-2)$ is a subfield of $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $K = \mathbb Q[x]/(x^3-2)$ and consider it as a subfield of $L$, then $K \cong \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]$ and $L \cong K[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$.

There are 6 ways which embeds $L$ into $\mathbb C$. Suppose we put $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3 - 2$ in $L$ and $\omega$ be a root of $x^2 + x + 1$ in $L$, then for $i = 1, 2, 3$, $\sigma_i: \alpha \mapsto \sqrt[3]2(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})^i$, and $\omega \mapsto \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $\bar\sigma_i$ gives three pairs of embeddings, which defines three archimedean places of $L$.

Comment: For any number field K (=finite extension of Q) of degree $n$, with $r$ real embeddings and $c$ couples of complex conjugate embeddings, you have $n=r+2c$.